# I have just started with angular and jodejs, I want to convert xml to json, I am confused between xmltojson and xml2json npm modules?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have two questions
1. why there are two alternatives available for same thing
2. how we should choose one of them, based on what criterion ?

my application is developed in ionic2, angular, android.

Also give me some more info about npm modules ? like who developes them ? is it open source ?

Answer (score -1):

while choosing NPM modules you need to check following criteria's like

1. How many people have installed this module for there project development. [you can check this in `weekly downloads`]
2. How many open issue's are there in Module.[ `open issues` section]
3. How frequently contributes supporting there modules. are there maintaining there project regularly ? [you can check this in `last publish`]
4. How neatly and accurately documentation is given for end user

These things are matters while choosing NPM modules wisely.